# Get product collection by store ID on Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, product, collection, filter, store-id

I want to get all products by **store ID**, so I'm doing it like this

```
return $this->productCollection->addStoreFilter(27);
```

**productCollection is**

> Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection

but instead, it returning the products by store, it returns all the products of all stores.

so can you please let me know how can I get only the product which belongs to store ID 27 or any given ID?

Comment: Have you found it's solution? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 7):

Please try this

```
<?php
namespace Meetanshi\Example\Block;
class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $storeid = 27; 
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addStoreFilter($storeid);        
        return $collection;
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this will help and make sure the id you are passing is available.

Comment: Of course , do not ever use object manager in your code unless you are creating  custom factory or proxy class. And '*' is very inefficient  way to build collections...

Comment: yes, you are right but its just for information.

Comment: And as a result we have to deal with modules making eyes bleeding every day... And I got feeling that he already have collection object created, isn't he?

Comment: But I believe `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` does not available on Magento 2.2?

Comment: ..and yes, I'm using class injection from the constructor, not object manager.

Comment: Hi
Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactor‌​y is a virtual class. I have updated a code as per constructor.

Comment: And I'm not sure if it important to mention that I'm building this as a Console command.

Comment: What do you mean with a virtual class? My editors says 
 Undefined Class: `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory`. I'm on magento 2.2.3

Comment: @FrankGroot That means the class do not really exist but Magento will create it anyway when you will execure your code..basically calling class A is the same as calling AFactory.

Answer (score 1):

This should work unless:

- Store do not exists
- You have already loaded collection items in some part of code that we do not see
- The products actually are in the store in filter

Another thing is that you started with collection but the question is about single product in a store. To get a single product you could use ProductRepository->get or getById
Both can be parameterized with storeId